# Azure devops infrustructure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I'm learning how to build the  infrastructure  provisioning  pipelines in Azure DevOps and looking for some step-by-step  tutorial to deploy for instance the vnet and  a VM in Azure using both methods - ARM templates as well as Terraform

Any help highly appreciated,

Thanks,
Andrey

Comment: What does the **both** mean? ARM used to deploy VM and Terraform used to deploy Vnet together? Or you just want to know the method in azure devops on how to deploy VM and Vnet with ARM or Terraform? These are different, please do clarify:-)

Comment: Yes I understand these are 2 different methods so I want to see both in action end-to-end and then select which one is more appropriate for my project. Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, got what you are looking. Would share my suggestion below~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ARM template:**

Firstly, you need have one template which it can be deployed to azure to create VM and Vnet. Just refer to this sample: [azure-quickstart-templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-1vm-2nics-2subnets-1vnet). Then do some changes into the JSON scripts based on your actual demands.

The CI/CD structure in azure devops also very easy.

**1)** Build:

Since the template scripts do not need any build process, it only need 2 tasks to pack and publish the repos as artifact. So that release can use them.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

**2)** Release:

In release pipeline, it just need one task: [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops).

This [blog](https://medium.com/faun/continuously-deploy-arm-templates-using-azure-devops-1855513c7d56) has detailed description on how to configure the task.

---

**Terraform:**

Same with ARM, here you also need one terraform scripts.

**1)** Build

For [tefrraform](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/azure-devops-terraform-deployment-with-azure-devops-part-1), the build configuration same with ARM. Just need publish artifacts.

**2)** Relesase

See this detailed [blog](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/azure-devops-terraform-deployment-with-azure-devops-part-2): Terraform deployment with Azure DevOps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints -  it looks simpler then I thought :-)

Comment: @Andrey, yeap! Pipeline configuration is very simple, just corresponding scripts(ARM or Terraform) prepared need time.